# ManagementEventWatcher event raised several times

Tags: windows, vb.net, usb

I'm detecting when a device is unplugged form the computer using:

```
Dim deviceRemovalQuery As New WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_DeviceChangeEvent WHERE EventType = 3")
PortRemoval = New ManagementEventWatcher(deviceRemovalQuery)
AddHandler PortRemoval.EventArrived, AddressOf RaisePortsRemoved
```

And when I effectively disconnect a device, the method `RaisePortsRemoved` is correctly called. But what I don't understand, it is called successively several times (5 times in my case) ?

I've checked, the `AddHandler` is called once, so why the event is fired multiple times ? Is there any away to avoid that, or should I implement a mechanism to avoid redundant calls ?

Comment: Just for S&G's, put `RemoveHandler PortRemoval.EventArrived, AddressOf RaisePortsRemoved` before AddHandler. This is a hacky but only reliable way to ensure you don't add multiple handlers dynamically.

Comment: Have you checked the object returned to the event handler which is a [ManagementEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventargs?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), which has a property [Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementeventargs.context?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#System_Management_ManagementEventArgs_Context) which may tell you more about each instance of the event?

Comment: @djv : yes I've tried to remove handler before but I still have the issue. However, I've checked the context, I'll take a look.

Comment: So I've checked the context, and each time, this context is empty (`Count = 0`).